# How to allow STS pop up on Cordova inAppbrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, uiwebview, uap

Some network asks STS username and Password (Plz check attached image) while accessing particular authentication page. While using Cordova inAppBrowser in an Cordova Application it stuck on the same place where the STS pop up arrives.

Platform : IOS / Android / Windows UAP
How can we enable STS pop up on inAppbrowser ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Nothing yet in InAppBrowser, I started using SafariViewController.